# Identifying what PASSWORD_DEFAULT will be in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, password-hash, php-7.4

Just before using `password_hash()`, I check if `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` === `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` to see if I need to do some cleanup on the password before it's hashed (Argon2 won't need this).

I'm simply passing it though a quick hash first, because bcrypt has an issue with NULL characters, and passwords longer than 72 characters ([more info](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016), and [a different example](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2016/09/how-dropbox-securely-stores-your-passwords/)).

But in PHP 7.4, the constant `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is now set to `NULL`.

So how can I tell what algorithm `password_hash()` will use?

Comment: Check the notes [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Specifically the ones above Changelog. I was going to quote it here, but it took too much space.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, sorry, I don't see how those notes relate to this problem. I'm not creating my own salt; the cost is do to with timing; and the point of my check is to support future algorithms that won't need the work arounds that bcrypt needs.

Comment: I am pretty sure that (most of) your answers all lie in the manual. If it doesn't, then please wait for someone who will be able to better answer what you're asking. From what I've read so far in the manual, it is clear as to which algo is used for the different ones listed / supported.

Comment: @AlexBarker, I'm not, I didn't mention anything about needing to re-hash... this is is applying a bit of cleanup to the user provided password, before it goes into `password_hash()`, because bcrypt has a couple of little issues... the way I do that cleanup is via a SHA hash, but that's not really relevant, I could do it in other ways... and I don't want to continue doing this cleanup for future algorithms (e.g. Argon2).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, When using `password_hash()` you can either specify which algorithm to use (not ideal), or you can tell it to use the `default`... I want to use the default, as Argon2 will eventually replace it (assuming no issues are found), but if that default is still bcrypt (which it is), then I need to do some cleanup first.

Comment: Sure but you can't specify Argon2 for PHP releases that don't support it. I'm sorry but I don't know any other way I could be of help.

Comment: *"as Argon2 will eventually replace it"* - I sincerely doubt that.

Comment: According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php, the default has never changed.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, the default will change, but only when the PHP developers are confident. At the moment the indication is that Argon2 will be the next one, as it has a few advantages over bcrypt... and I want to be ready for that, rather than hard coding the use of bcrypt with it’s work arounds.

Comment: @aynber, the idea is that it will change, it’s why we have a constant defined for that, otherwise it would effectively hard code which algorithm to use.

Comment: @CraigFrancis - I'm interested about the issues you had with bcrypt, actually it shouldn't matter at all what you pass to the function, does it?

Comment: @martinstoeckli the two links in the question will explain better than I can, but bcrypt has a couple of small issues, found over the years which have been addressed with Argon2, but that’s a fairly new algorithm, so isn’t widely trusted yet.

Comment: @CraigFrancis - Thanks for the links. Actually the 72 char limit isn't an issue at all, because one _can_ hash longer passwords, and a truncated password with 72 chars is still so strong, that key stretching is not even necessary. But I understand now why you wanted to distinguish the parameter.

Comment: @martinstoeckli there is a question mark over the 72 character limit, in that different implementations might do different things (I am under the impression that it’s undefined behaviour on what it should do).

Comment: @CraigFrancis - So then your goal is to ensure compatibility between different libraries?

Comment: @martinstoeckli yep, especially as libraries might change with version upgrades.

Comment: This is now fixed in PHP 7.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit***

As of PHP 7.4.3 you can continue using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT === PASSWORD_BCRYPT`

*https://3v4l.org/nN4Qi*

---

You don't actually have to use `password_hash` twice. A better and faster way is to provide an already hashed value with `Bcrypt` and check it against `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` with
 [password_needs_rehash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) function to see if the default algo has changed or not.

> bcrypt algorithm is the default as of PHP 5.5.0

So for example:

```
$hash = '$2y$10$ra4VedcLU8bv3jR0AlpEau3AZevkQz4Utm7F8EqUNE0Jqx0s772NG'; // Bcrypt hash

// if it doesn't need rehash then the default algo is absolutely Bcrypt
if (! password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
    // do some clean up
}
```

> **Note**: make sure that the hash value($hash) has the same cost provided in `password_needs_rehash`'s third parameter, otherwise it will consider the hash outdated and need rehash since the cost has changed.

Comment: Thanks for the update @rain, the bug report that tracked this change is at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78969 ... and your suggestion of using `password_needs_rehash()` is clever, and much faster; but I must admit, I'll probably keep with `password_hash()` twice for PHP 7.4.0 - 7.4.2, as that's more of a direct check (ref the cost change issue you mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem, for which I believe there is no standard function yet. This is not a huge problem because the hash itself contains an identifier telling us which hash algorithm was used. The important thing to note here is that `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is a **constant**. Constants do not change.

To figure out which algorithm is used when using the default constant (which was and still is bcrypt), you need to generate some dummy hash and look at the beginning of it. We can even use a nice helper function [`password_get_info()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-get-info.php)

```
$hashInfo = password_get_info(password_hash('pass', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, [ 'cost' => 4 ] ));
echo $hashInfo['algo']; // should return either 1 or 2y

if($hashInfo['algo'] === PASSWORD_BCRYPT) {
    // will be true for PHP <= 7.4
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the constant did change between PHP 7.3 and 7.4 (it used to be 1 for bcrypt, it's now NULL with "2y" representing PASSWORD_BCRYPT)... but I think you're right, while I was hoping I wouldn't need to use the password_hash() function twice, as each time adds 100ms to the processing time, this would work.

Comment: Which is why I used the lowest possible cost. It should not take 100 ms

Comment: Sorry, yes, I didn't see that (chalk it up to a late night), thanks Dharman.

Comment: “Constants do not change” — actually, they may well change between implementations. The reason we use a named constant is that the value is allowed to change without upsetting our code.